# IP Address in openID/OAuth id_token Claims and in SAML response in Forgerock

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect, openid, saml-2.0, forgerock

Is it possible to retrieve User’s IP Address from openID/OAuth Claims and in SAML response. Do we have anywhere to add this or tune up something in configuration in FORGEROCK.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to retrieve User’s IP Address from openID/OAuth Claims
> and in SAML response

First of all, why you need to obtain the IP Address from the `Authorization server` and `Identity provider`? I guess, you'll be more interested in to find out the connected user's or client's IP address and that could be easily obtained from the incoming `http request` landing to your server.